# Home Project - Interactive Travel Map with Pins & Pictures

Tags: google-maps, raspberry-pi, openstreetmap, raspberry-pi3

I am thinking about starting a project for my house.

I envisage a large monitor somewhere in my house (likely a 32+ inch TV) that acts as an interactive photo frame.

I want to display a map, with pins of the places I've visited.

I would like a program to scroll through these pins (zoom out to the world map, then scroll and zoom to a set level to a pin) in some sort of sequence. Each pin that it reaches, some sort of overlay will appear (Ideally) and display images with a description of the trip. I may shorten the scope to a new window appearing in the short term.

I am in no major rush to start this project, I am just wondering what sort of technologies you guys think I could use to create this application.

I have Java experience, Python experience, Javascript experience, and have previously embedded Google maps and utilized google maps APIs in an android application.

I plan to run this on a raspberry PI hidden behind the screen.

Thanks in advance!
Tom

Answer (score 1):

To give you a start, watch this demo on site for animated google map creation.
It almost has all you have described so far. I guess as your tour images are not going to change very soon, a video prepared and played in loop mode on your TV can take away lot of efforts. Hoping to discuss more on this down the road. 
http://www.animaps.com/pb/88280001/6820/New_Showcase

Youtube Video of [creating virtual tours on Google Earth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQvrB5aRV_Q) here